# How do I add Poisson noise to a greyscale image in Python using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, noise-generator

I'm trying to implement adding Poisson noise to a greyscale image using `numpy` as a `Pytorch` transformer but so far my results have been very disappointing. Here are my various implementations with results ranging from seeing no visible changes to only seeing noise without an image. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
class Noise(object):
  def __init__(self, noise_type):
    self.noise_type = noise_type

  def __call__(self, sample):
    noise = np.random.poisson(1, sample.shape)
    return sample + noise
```

but as I understand it, Poisson noise can't be simply added to an image which is why all I see here is noise (kind of like TV static) without the original greyscale image.

The following version of the code yields no visible changes in the image which leads me to believe it's some sort of scaling issue since in Poisson noise, noise is added relative to a pixel's value.

```
vals = len(np.unique(sample))
vals = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(vals))
noisy = np.random.poisson(sample * vals) / float(vals)
return noisy
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use PyTorch for the whole thing? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I understand there are ready-made layers in Pytorch for such things, but I wish to create a semi-synthetic dataset from my current images. So I want my images to flow from my PyTorch Dataset with transforms applied to them

Comment: Not what I meant. You can use [`torch.distributions.poisson.Poisson`] and `sample` to generate noise and add it to image. Oh, BTW, you can use [torchdata](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchdata) for easier `mapping` (or as you say transforms) samples to noise and stuff like that (disclaimer: I'm an author).

Comment: Oh, about adding poisson. You should `clip` your values to `[0, 1]` range so it's valid (and appropriate rate for the noise). And no, it's not dependent on your sample IIRC and you can simply add it (after clipping at least).